# I have problem converting .pb file to .tflite file

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I have problem converting `.pb` file to `.tflite` file.

I use the below command;

tried using the below command and different options with `--inference_type=FLOAT`

```
        tflite_convert 
        --graph_def_file=frozen_inference_graph.pb 
        --output_file=new_graph.tflite 
        --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF 
        --output_format=TFLITE 
        --input_shape=1,600,600,3 
        --input_array=image_tensor 
        --output_array=detection_boxes,detection_scores,detection_classes,num_detections 
        --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 
        --inference_input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8
```

I get **error** stating;

> ValueError: std_dev and mean must be defined when inference_input_type is QUANTIZED_UINT8. Please help if you had faced the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use quantized values for inference, you need to define the standard deviation and the mean of the training data since it is used to map between floating points and int8 in the following way.

```
real_input_value = (quantized_input_value - mean_value) / std_dev_value
```

This is defined in the [TFLiteConverter documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the std_dev and mean flag while doing the conversion. like this:

```
tflite_convert 
        --graph_def_file=frozen_inference_graph.pb 
        --output_file=new_graph.tflite 
        --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF 
        --output_format=TFLITE 
        --input_shape=1,600,600,3 
        --input_array=image_tensor 
        --output_array=detection_boxes,detection_scores,detection_classes,num_detections 
        --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 
        --inference_input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8
        --mean_values=128 \
        --std_dev_values=127
```

Hope that helped.regards